# Avoiding function calls in 'where' clause of sql queries generated by django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

The Django generating sql queries with function calls in `where` clause like below, when using Django queries for search or any other purposes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "_count" 
FROM "products_product" 
    INNER JOIN "products_productmeta" ON ("products_product"."meta_id" = "products_productmeta"."id") 
WHERE ((NOT ("products_product"."archived" = true) AND
        "products_product"."owner_id" = 1281 AND
        UPPER(UNACCENT("products_product"."sku")::text) LIKE '%' || 
        UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((UNACCENT('octavi')), '\', '\'), '%', '\%'), '', '_')) || 
        '%') OR 
       (NOT ("productsproduct"."archived" = true) AND 
        "products_product"."owner_id" = 1281 AND 
        UPPER(UNACCENT("products_productmeta"."name")::text) LIKE '%' || 
        UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((UNACCENT('octavi')), '\', '\'), '%', '\%'), '', '_')) || 
        '%')
       )
```

Response time is taking too long with these type of queries because of whole data sets are passing through the function calls.

Is there any way to avoid those function calls such as `UPPER`, `REPLACE` etc... in `where` clause of sql generated by django?

Is writing raw sql queries the only option?

**EDIT:** Django query example with SQL string output added:

```
Product.objects.filter(meta__name__icontains="foo").query.sql_with_params()
```

The simple Django query above is generating SQL string below:

```
('SELECT 
    "products_product"."id", 
    ....
    "products_product"."is_primary"
FROM "products_product" 
INNER JOIN "products_productmeta" ON ("products_product"."meta_id" = "products_productmeta"."id") 
WHERE (NOT ("products_product"."archived" = %s) AND
       UPPER("products_productmeta"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER(%s))', 
(True, '%foo%'))
```

As you can see; Django adding function calls to `where` clause. I want to remove that function calls. Complex queries are taking too long time.

Comment: Can you also include the Django ORM query you're using that's generating this SQL? It seems like you're asking if there's a way to optimize at that level, so you should show what that code looks like.

Comment: Writing raw queries shouldn't be your first option at all unless the ORM cannot handle the desired queries

Comment: Some conditions here are *very* strange. For example the `LIKE '%'` is trivially `True` (except for `NULL`).

Comment: @MihaiChelaru related case, reproduced with example query which is added to question.